# Parsing a JSON API in Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I'm building a node wrapper for an external API and am having issues parsing the JSON response. The following code makes the request:

```
https = require "https"
querystring = require "querystring"

API_HOST = "api.lob.com"
API_PATH = "/v1"

startResponseHandler = (req, cb) ->
  if typeof cb isnt "function" then console.log "Error: callback needs to be a function!"
  req.on 'response', (res) ->
    response = ''
    res.setEncoding 'utf8'
    res.on 'data', (stream) ->
      response += stream
    res.on 'end', () ->
      error = null
      try
        response = JSON.parse response
        if res.statusCode != 200 or 201
          response = null
          error = new Error response.error.message
          error.name = response.error.type
          error.code = response.error.code
          error.param = response.error.param
      catch e
        error = new Error "Invalid JSON"
        response = null
      cb error, response
  req.on 'error', (error) ->
    cb error

module.exports = lob = (api_key) ->

  # This function makes the request
  makeRequest = (method, path, data, cb) ->
    data = querystring.stringify data
    options = 
      hostname: API_HOST
      path: "#{API_PATH}/#{path}"
      method: method
      auth: "#{api_key}:"
      headers:
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        'Content-Length' : data.length
    req = https.request options
    startResponseHandler req, cb
    req.write data if method is "POST" or "PUT"
    req.end()

  # GET, POST, DELETE, PUT functions
  _get = (path, cb) ->
    makeRequest "GET", path, {}, cb

  _post = (path, data, cb) ->
    makeRequest "POST", path, data, cb

  _del = (path, cb) ->
    makeRequest "DELETE", path, {}, cb

  _put = (path, data, cb) ->
    makeRequest "PUT", path, data, cb

  # Jobs
  jobs:

    createJob: (data, cb) ->
      _post "/jobs/", data, cb
```

And the below code was written to test the wrapper:

```
api_key = "test_0dc8d51e0acffcb1880e0f19c79b2f5b0cc"

lob     = require('../src/lob')(api_key)
should  = require("should")
chai    = require("chai")

data = 
  name: "Michigan fan letter"
  to: "adr_43769b47aed248c2"
  from: "adr_7f9ece71fbca3796"
  object1: "obj_7ca5f80b42b6dfca"
  object2: "obj_12128d3aad2aa98f"

describe "Job", ->
  @timeout(10000)
  describe "create", ->
    it "should create a job with address_id", (done) ->
      lob.jobs.createJob data , (new_job) ->
        new_job['name'].should.equal(data['name'])
        done()
```

However, when I run the mocha test (`$ mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script`) I receive the following error:

```
1) Job create should create a job with address_id:

      + expected - actual

      +"Michigan fan letter"
      -"Error"
```

**EDIT**

Below is the response from `stream` inside `res.on 'data'`:

```
{
    "id": "job_7ecc50bea15178b8e07a",
    "name": "Michigan fan letter",
    "price": "1.26",
    "to": {
        "id": "adr_43769b47aed248c2",
        "name": "Harry Zhang",
        "email": "harry@lob.com",
        "phone": "5555555555",
        "address_line1": "123 Test Street",
        "address_line2": "Unit 199",
        "address_city": "Mountain View",
        "address_state": "CA",
        "address_zip": "94085",
        "address_country": "UNITED STATES",
        "date_created": "2013-07-20T05:53:25+00:00",
        "date_modified": "2013-07-20T05:53:25+00:00",
        "object": "address"
    },
    "from": {
        "id": "adr_7f9ece71fbca3796",
        "name": "Harry Zhang",
        "email": "harry@lob.com",
        "phone": "5555555555",
        "address_line1": "123 Test Avenue",
        "address_line2": "Unit 401",
        "address_city": "Seattle",
        "address_state": "WA",
        "address_zip": "98122",
        "address_country": "UNITED STATES",
        "date_created": "2013-07-20T05:55:19+00:00",
        "date_modified": "2013-07-20T05:55:19+00:00",
        "object": "address"
    },
    "status": "processed",
    "tracking": null,
    "packaging": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Smart Packaging",
        "description": "Automatically determined optimal packaging for safe and secure delivery",
        "object": "packaging"
    },
    "service": null,
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": "obj_7ca5f80b42b6dfca",
            "name": "Michigan is great",
            "quantity": "1",
            "full_bleed": "0",
            "double_sided": "0",
            "date_created": "2013-07-20T05:57:32+00:00",
            "date_modified": "2013-07-20T05:57:32+00:00",
            "setting": {
                "id": "101",
                "type": "Documents",
                "description": "Color Document",
                "paper": "20lb Paper Standard",
                "width": "8.500",
                "length": "11.000",
                "color": "Color",
                "notes": "50 cents per extra page",
                "object": "setting"
            },
            "url": "http://assets.lob.com/obj_7ca5f80b42b6dfca",
            "object": "object"
        },
        {
            "id": "obj_12128d3aad2aa98f",
            "name": "GO BLUE",
            "quantity": "1",
            "full_bleed": "0",
            "double_sided": "0",
            "date_created": "2013-07-31T00:58:35+00:00",
            "date_modified": "2013-07-31T00:58:35+00:00",
            "setting": {
                "id": "100",
                "type": "Documents",
                "description": "Black and White Document",
                "paper": "20lb Paper Standard",
                "width": "8.500",
                "length": "11.000",
                "color": "Black and White",
                "notes": "12 cents per extra page",
                "object": "setting"
            },
            "url": "http://assets.lob.com/obj_12128d3aad2aa98f",
            "object": "object"
        }
    ],
    "date_created": "2014-01-25T03:10:10+00:00",
    "date_modified": "2014-01-25T03:10:10+00:00",
    "object": "job"
}
```

Which exactly matches up to the example response in the [documentation](https://www.lob.com/docs)

```
{
    "id": "job_754d8b14dd31587d6873",
    "name": "Michigan fan letter",
    "price": "0.96",
    "to": {
        "id": "adr_43769b47aed248c2",
        "name": "Harry Zhang",
        "email": "harry@lob.com",
        "phone": "5555555555",
        "address_line1": "123 Test Street",
        "address_line2": "Unit 199",
        "address_city": "Mountain View",
        "address_state": "CA",
        "address_zip": "94085",
        "address_country": "UNITED STATES",
        "date_created": "2013-07-20T05:53:25+00:00",
        "date_modified": "2013-07-20T05:53:25+00:00",
        "object": "address"
    },
    "from": {
        "id": "adr_7f9ece71fbca3796",
        "name": "Harry Zhang",
        "email": "harry@lob.com",
        "phone": "5555555555",
        "address_line1": "123 Test Avenue",
        "address_line2": "Unit 401",
        "address_city": "Seattle",
        "address_state": "WA",
        "address_zip": "98122",
        "address_country": "UNITED STATES",
        "date_created": "2013-07-20T05:55:19+00:00",
        "date_modified": "2013-07-20T05:55:19+00:00",
        "object": "address"
    },
    "status": "processed",
    "tracking": null,
    "packaging": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Smart Packaging",
        "description": "Automatically determined optimal packaging for safe and secure delivery",
        "object": "packaging"
    },
    "service": null,
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": "obj_7ca5f80b42b6dfca",
            "name": "Michigan is great",
            "quantity": "1",
            "full_bleed": "0",
            "double_sided": "0",
            "date_created": "2013-07-20T05:57:32+00:00",
            "date_modified": "2013-07-20T05:57:32+00:00",
            "setting": {
                "id": "101",
                "type": "Documents",
                "description": "Color Document",
                "paper": "20lb Paper Standard",
                "width": "8.500",
                "length": "11.000",
                "color": "Color",
                "notes": "50 cents per extra page",
                "object": "setting"
            },
            "object": "object"
        }
    ],
    "date_created": "2014-01-18T19:52:27+00:00",
    "date_modified": "2014-01-18T19:52:27+00:00",
    "object": "job"
}
```

Here is the data from `JSON.parse response`

```
{ id: 'job_9973e060bd8147f97f5f',
  name: 'Michigan fan letter',
  price: '1.26',
  to:
   { id: 'adr_43769b47aed248c2',
     name: 'Harry Zhang',
     email: 'harry@lob.com',
     phone: '5555555555',
     address_line1: '123 Test Street',
     address_line2: 'Unit 199',
     address_city: 'Mountain View',
     address_state: 'CA',
     address_zip: '94085',
     address_country: 'UNITED STATES',
     date_created: '2013-07-20T05:53:25+00:00',
     date_modified: '2013-07-20T05:53:25+00:00',
     object: 'address' },
  from:
   { id: 'adr_7f9ece71fbca3796',
     name: 'Harry Zhang',
     email: 'harry@lob.com',
     phone: '5555555555',
     address_line1: '123 Test Avenue',
     address_line2: 'Unit 401',
     address_city: 'Seattle',
     address_state: 'WA',
     address_zip: '98122',
     address_country: 'UNITED STATES',
     date_created: '2013-07-20T05:55:19+00:00',
     date_modified: '2013-07-20T05:55:19+00:00',
     object: 'address' },
  status: 'processed',
  tracking: null,
  packaging:
   { id: '1',
     name: 'Smart Packaging',
     description: 'Automatically determined optimal packaging for safe and secure delivery',
     object: 'packaging' },
  service: null,
  objects:
   [ { id: 'obj_7ca5f80b42b6dfca',
       name: 'Michigan is great',
       quantity: '1',
       full_bleed: '0',
       double_sided: '0',
       date_created: '2013-07-20T05:57:32+00:00',
       date_modified: '2013-07-20T05:57:32+00:00',
       setting: [Object],
       url: 'http://assets.lob.com/obj_7ca5f80b42b6dfca',
       object: 'object' },
     { id: 'obj_12128d3aad2aa98f',
       name: 'GO BLUE',
       quantity: '1',
       full_bleed: '0',
       double_sided: '0',
       date_created: '2013-07-31T00:58:35+00:00',
       date_modified: '2013-07-31T00:58:35+00:00',
       setting: [Object],
       url: 'http://assets.lob.com/obj_12128d3aad2aa98f',
       object: 'object' } ],
  date_created: '2014-01-25T23:12:37+00:00',
  date_modified: '2014-01-25T23:12:37+00:00',
  object: 'job' }
```

Comment: Have you watched `stream` inside `res.on 'data'` to see if it is what you're expecting it to be? Same for `response` inside `res.on 'end'`.

Comment: I'm not logging the contents, but a 201 header is returned which shows that the POST request was successfully made

Comment: Start logging it, if `JSON.parse` is complaining then maybe you're not getting the data you think you're getting.

Comment: Good advice! I've updated the question with response from `JSON.parse`

Comment: So is that a JSON string or a JavaScript object? `JSON.parse` expects a string.

Comment: If `JSON.parse` is returning a valid object, why would there be an error thrown?

Comment: Can you get a strack trace from the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems in that code. I don't usually use CoffeeScript. So if I'm misreading please correct me:

1. The callback is called like this:

   ```
   cb error, response
   ```

   First argument is an error object and the second argument is the response, however in the test the callback is like this:

   ```
   lob.jobs.createJob data , (new_job) ->
            new_job['name'].should.equal(data['name'])
   ```

   So `new_job` is the error object. This does not explain everything, however, because you *are* getting an error. But even if there were no error, the value of `new_job` would not be the response.

   The reason the test shows that the string `Error` is the actual value is that `Error` objects have a `name` field which is set to the name of the class of the exception. (So `new Error().name` evaluates to `"Error"`.)
2. This section of code also looks incorrect:

   ```
   try
     response = JSON.parse response
     if res.statusCode != 200 or 201
       response = null
       error = new Error response.error.message
       error.name = response.error.type
       error.code = response.error.code
       error.param = response.error.param
   catch e
     error = new Error "Invalid JSON"
     response = null
   cb error, response
   ```

   In the `if` branch the `response` is set to `null` and then some fields of `response` are accessed. This will cause an exception. And this exception will then be interpreted as bad JSON due to the way the `try... catch` clause is set. The `try... catch` clause should be narrowed to cover only the `JSON.parse` call:

   ```
   try
     response = JSON.parse response
   catch e
     error = new Error "Invalid JSON"
     response = null
   ```
3. This test is incorrect:

   ```
     if res.statusCode != 200 or 201
   ```

   It becomes JavaScript:

   ```
     if (res.statusCode !== 200 || 201)
   ```

   The part after the `||` makes it always true. Something like the following CoffeeScript code seems to be what is intended:

   ```
     if res.statusCode not in [200, 201]
   ```

So it does not matter if the request is successful or not. Because of the third problem, the`if` test will always be true, the branch always will be taken and the second problem will always occur. So the Mocha test will always fail.

Comment: quick note - With this setup, if I drop in `console.log res.statusCode` it returns `200`

Comment: So it does not solve your immediate problem. Fair enough, but it's still bad code.

Comment: With the third point I've added, I might have covered everything.